# How to iterate over map and conver it to the vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a map in c++:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map <int,int> map;
    int k;
    cin >> k;

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
    {
        int m;
        cin >> m;
        map.at(m)++;
    }      
}
```

How can I iterate over this map and add all values of it to vector?

So map look like this:

```
pair<int, int>(1, 40)
pair<int, int>(22, 30)
pair<int, int>(34, 60)
pair<int, int>(41, 20)
pair<int, int>(5, 50)
pair<int, int>(6, 50)
pair<int, int>(7, 10)
```

I want to push the values of this to vector. So the vector will look like this: [40, 30, 60, 20, 50, 50, 10]

Comment: A vector of *what*? What is the data that you want to add to the vector? What have you tried yourself? What problems do you have with your own attempt? Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Check now the ask

Comment: On another couple of notes, the code you currently show won't work because the [`at`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) function will not add new elements to the map. Instead it will throw an exception. Also please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).

Comment: It does not compile `bez nazwy.cpp:17:50: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >&' from an rvalue of type 'std::vector<int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >}'`

Comment: `std::map` is sorted by the key, and in your example pairs are not sorted w.r.t the first element. Does the order of elements in the resulting vector matter?

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
int main() {
 std::map<int, int> mapData{ {1,40},{22,30},{34,60},{41,20},{5,50},{6,50},{7,10}};
 std::vector<int> values{};
 for (const auto& [key, value] : mapData)
  values.push_back(value);
 return 0;
}

Comment: In case you want to do is to add all map values to a new vector you can do:

    `map<int, int> m; // The original map
    vector<int> v; // The destination vector
    for(map<int,int>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
      v.push_back(it->second);
    }`

Comment: The order does not matter

Answer (score 1):

Using `std::copy` is not the best idea because the `value_type` of the map is `std::pair<const int, int>` and of the vector is simply `int`, so I will use `std::for_each` which allows you to copy in your specific way.

`std::for_each`.

Example:

```cpp
std::map<int, int> map;
std::vector<int> vec;
...
std::for_each(map.begin(), map.end(), [&vec](const auto pair) {
    vec.push_back(pair.second);
});
```

`std::transform`

```cpp
std::transform(map.begin(), map.end(), std::back_inserter(vec), [](const auto pair) { return pair.second; });
```

Comment: or std::transform

Comment: how to use std transform?

Comment: ```cpp
std::map<int, int> map;
std::vector<int> vec;
...
std::transform(map.begin(), map.end(), std::back_inserter(vec), [](const auto pair) {
    return pair.second;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

std::vector<int> map_to_vector( const std::map<int, int> &m )
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve( m.size() );

    for ( const auto &p : m )
    {
        v.push_back( p.second );
    }

    return v;
}

int main() 
{
    std::map<int, int> m =
    {
        { 1, 40 }, { 22, 30 }, { 34, 60 }, { 41, 20 }, { 5, 50 }, { 6, 50 }, { 7, 10 }
    };

    auto v = map_to_vector( m );

    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
40 50 50 10 30 60 20
```

Payb attention that the map is ordered by its key. So the vector will contain values in the order according to the order of keys in the map.

Or as it was written by **@Jerry Jeremiah** in a comment you can use the standard algorithm `std::transform`.

```
std::vector<int> map_to_vector( const std::map<int, int> &m )
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.reserve( m.size() );

    std::transform( std::begin( m ), std::end( m ), std::back_inserter( v ),
                    []( const auto &p ) { return p.second; } );
    return v;
}
```

Comment: Ok it works good, why I cannot sort this auto v?

Comment: @michel I have not understood what you mean. You can sort the vector. What is the problem?

Comment: I get this error `bez nazwy.cpp:35:26: error: no matching function for call to 'sort(<unresolved overloaded function type>, std::vector<int>::iterator)'`

Comment: @michel std::sort( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ) );

Comment: why `sort(v.begin(), v.end()) does not work`?
Of course I am using namespace std;

Comment: @michel Can you at least copy and paste the statement as is I showed in the previous comment? It works.